# Is there any convincing reason why a truststore/keystore requires a password?

Tags: java

The standard java truststore/keystore has a publicly wide known password.
I assume good architecture requires I create my own truststore/keystore.

Why would I want to secure it with a password?

Say: I have an SSL certificate inside: it's of no use to anyone else than the server for which it has been issued.

Say: I can always create a new truststore/keystore with new certificates and the same filename.

I don't understand why bothering with a password.. Anyone?

Comment: Suppose anyone could add trusted status to any certificate they wanted. Seem like a good idea?

Comment: "The standard java truststore/keystore has a publicly wide known password" I guess you're talking about **changeit**? Does the name not give you a clue as to the intention for this?

Comment: If you have the private key of your ssl certificate inside, it's very interesting for a hacker wanting to execute a man-in-the-middle attack. Or dns-related hacks.

Answer (score 0):

The keystore password serves only as an integrity protection. If you try to use a blank password:

```
*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************
* The integrity of the information stored in your keystore  *
* has NOT been verified!  In order to verify its integrity, *
* you must provide your keystore password.                  *
*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************
```